# How to execute only after all AJAXcalls are made?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As you can see function `getPollById` is called depending on the `responselength`, so for every response, the API makes a call to access the data. Using `$q.all`, I am unable to execute after everything has been executed. So how do I execute after all calls are made? What mistake am I making here? I am getting the consoled.log after the first function. I want after the `getPollById` finished requesting for the entire `response.length`. How do I do it ?

```
adminApp.controller('PollController', function($scope,$window,$timeout, $rootScope,$routeParams, $http, $location, $q ) {
    displayLoader("Loading...", "100px");
    var httpData1 = $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: "the url",
    }).
    success(function(response) {
        $scope.poll = response;            
        for (var i =  0; i < response.length; i++) {
            getPollById(response[i], i);
            angular.element('#loadering').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    }).
    error(function(response) {
        console.log(response || "Request failed");
    });
    var httpData2;

    function getPollById(i, index){
        httpData2 =  $http({
            method: 'post',
            url:  BASE_URL+'admin_api/admin_poll_api/admin_poll/',
            data: i
        }).
        success(function(response) {
            appendData(response, index);
            var labels = [];
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.response.options.length; i++) {    
                labels.push(response.response.options[i].options);
                data.push(response.response.options[i].votes);
            }
        }). 
        error(function(response) {
            console.log(response || "Request failed");
        });
    }

    $scope.polls=[];
    function appendData(response, index){
        $scope.polls[index] = response;
    }
    $q.all([httpData1, httpData2]).then(function() {
        console.log("all calls have finished ");
    })  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter initialized to 0. Increment it each time a get/post is finished. Call the function you want to execute only if the counter gets to the number of get/posts you want.

Answer (score 0):

at the time of execution, there is only one promise to resolve - `httpData1`

you have to call `$q.all` after `httpData2` is set

the problem is that you may have more than one additional promise to resolve, so you should collect them and return as a bulk promise:

```
adminApp.controller('PollController', function($scope,$window,$timeout, $rootScope,$routeParams, $http, $location, $q ) {
    displayLoader("Loading...", "100px");
    $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: "the url",
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.poll = response;
        var promises = [];

        for (var i =  0; i < response.length; i++) {
            promises.push(getPollById(response[i], i));
            angular.element('#loadering').fadeOut('slow');
        }

        return $q.all(promises);
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response || "Request failed");
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("all calls have finished ");
    })

    function getPollById(i, index)
    {
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            url:  BASE_URL+'admin_api/admin_poll_api/admin_poll/',
            data: i

        }).then(function(response) {
            appendData(response, index);
            var labels = [];
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.response.options.length; i++) {
                labels.push(response.response.options[i].options);
                data.push(response.response.options[i].votes);
            }
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response || "Request failed");
        });
    }

    $scope.polls=[];
    function appendData(response, index){
        $scope.polls[index] = response;

    }
});
```

what I have done here is to chain your main promise with bulk of additional promises

Comment: But I am not getting the response from the second API Call, from function getPollById.

Comment: No errors but it is not being called. I am trying to perform $q.all after all the AJAX calls have been made. But this does not call to the `code`admin_poll`code`.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that $q.all will exit after first reject, if you want to be sure that all promises ended (resolved or rejected), you may use angular promise extras module (https://github.com/ohjames/angular-promise-extras) whith its $q.allSettled method. So you can just replace $q.all() in pwolaq's nice answer with:

```
$q.allSettled (promises);
```